# Resetting Sign in With Apple and 'forgetting' user choice

Tags: ios, sign-in-with-apple

I'm using sign in with apple on a few apps and have found an issue:

If the user selects "Hide my email" and then signs out and tries to sign in again, they don't get the option to choose whether to Hide or Show again, it just continues to use the anonymous email.

In my case, when the email is hidden certain aspects of the app do not work so we encourage the user to share their email.

I need the user to be able to logout and then "undo" the hide, but it is not obvious how to do this or if it's even possible programmatically.

Comment: This would create a second account. Instead, ask the person for their email address, and link it to the account. Apple recommends this approach: "If you choose Hide My Email ... You can also choose to share your personal email address with a developer directly from their app or website." Users can change their email addresses over time, so a mechanism for email linking is generally important in systems. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210425

Comment: They need to into the account in the device settings, and under "password and security" and "apps using appleid" they can find your app/web site. They can then select to "stop using Apple ID". This has the effect of deleting their account.  If they then select Sign In with Apple again in your app, your app will see them as a new user, with a new unique identifier.  Note that choosing to hide their email address is a user choice and not something that you should attempt to control.

Comment: You can ask the user in your app to provide an alternate email address.  Note that there should be no effective difference between using a private relay address and their actual address In terms of your ability to send them email (unless they turn off the relay because they no longer want your email)

Comment: I'd also point to the "Prevent Duplicate Accounts" section, which recommends asking the user for other email addresses and linking the accounts inside your system (if your system is already tied to the other email). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple